# Modify footnote properties in optex

Tags: plain-tex, opmac, optex

How do I modify the behavior of the footnote line and text with optex?

I'd like to change the width and height of the rule, and the footnotes to hang thus:

```
¹ Text text text
  text text text
  text text text
```

I've tried changing `footnoterule`, but it didn't work.

```
\def\footnoterule{\vfill % added this
   \kern-3pt\hrule width 1cm \kern 2.6pt} % doesn't work
   
% \footnoterulewidth 1cm % doesn't work
  
\fnote{asdf}

\bye
```

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you want to achieve with that `\vfill`.

Comment: @egreg, nothing in particular. I just copied it from a question here (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/573538/force-footnotes-to-bottom-of-page-in-plain-tex). I just want to redefine `footnoterule` _and_ make them hang.

Comment: Do you just want to change the length/width of the footnote rule, and have hanging footnote paragraphs?

Comment: @jarnosz, yes, that's it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you realized, OpTeX is not quite "Plain" according to a strict description: it has its own internals somewhat differing from Plain itself; that of itself is not evil, just slightly misleading.

Anyway, to set the hanging indent to your footnotes add the following redefinition to your document.

```
\_def\_fnset{\everypar={\hangindent=1.5cc\hangafter=1}\_scalemain \_typoscale[800/800]}
```

To change the footnote rule:

```
\_def \_footnoterule {\_kern-3pt \_hrule width 1truein height 2pt \_kern 2.6pt }
```

[image: visual result]

Comment: thank you so much! Worked like a charm.

Comment: I included similar answer on the OpTeX tricks web page http://petr.olsak.net/optex/optex-tricks.html#fnindent